# FB.getLoginStatus Requires Page Refresh before Firing

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk

I have a Facebook Page Tab App that is not loading correctly until after the page is refreshed. I have been trying to solve this problem for over a week, and am reaching my wits end.

Here is the code:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https:////connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : '***************', // App ID
          channelURL : '//www.********.com/**********/channel.html', // Channel File
          status     : true, // check login status
          cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
          oauth      : true, // enable OAuth 2.0
          xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
        });

        // Additional initialization code here
      };

      // Load the SDK Asynchronously
      (function(d){
         var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
         d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
       }(document));
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                //User Logged In
            }
            else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                //Log User Into App
            }
            else
            {
                top.location = "http://www.facebook.com";
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Like I said, if add something like `alert("Test")` immediately after `FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {` it doesn't pop up on the first page load, but does after the page is refreshed.

Can someone please help point me in the right direction?

Thanks,
Fred

Comment: did you try doing it on window.load instead of document.ready??

Comment: I tried window.ready and document.ready, both with the same result. But either way those are firing fine, it's just FB.getLoginStatus that isn't firing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you are loading the SDK both Synchronously and Asynchronously. Remove the synchronous line. Then all your FB related lines should be within the window.fbAsyncInit. You can't subscribe to events before the sdk is fully loaded.

Comment: No problem. Glad to be of help.

Comment: did you mean to remove all of this? `window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : '***************', // App ID
          channelURL : '//www.********.com/**********/channel.html', // Channel File
          status     : true, // check login status
          cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
          oauth      : true, // enable OAuth 2.0
          xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
        });

        // Additional initialization code here
      };`

Answer (score 1):

You can try it this way if you haven't already

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.authResponse) {
   // logged in and connected user, someone you know
  } else {
    // no user session available, someone you dont know
  }
});
```

Comment: This may in fact be a better way to do perform the check, BUT... all that is different from mine is `if (response.authResponse)` which it does not get to until I reload the page, because `FB.getLoginStatus` does not fire until after a page reload.

Comment: what if you move the FB.getLoginStatus inside window.fbAsyncInit